# How to Load Sprite into Sprite Renderer from SVGImage by Using Vector Graphic in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, svg

I want to load Sprite From SVG image into SpriteRenderer Component of GameObject.

```
     private void Start()
    {
    LoadSpriteFromSVG();
    }

public void LoadSpriteFromSVG()
    {
    SVGImage image = Resources.Load<SVGImage>("Nadeem");

    transform.GetComponent<SVGImage>().sprite = image.sprite;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Nadeem vector image is an imported Vector Sprite/Textured Sprite/Texture 2D (depending on your import settings), not an SVGImage, which is instead a MonoBehaviour derived Script component. The following code should work if your Nadeem image is being imported as a Vector Sprite or Textured Sprite:

```cs
private void Start()
{
    LoadSpriteFromSVG();
}

public void LoadSpriteFromSVG()
{
    Sprite image = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Nadeem");

    transform.GetComponent<SVGImage>().sprite = image;
}
```